# Adding group_id to notes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm looking to build an application where a `user` can sign in, create a `group` and post `notes` in the group. `user` must be able to invite other `user` to the `group` if they already exist, and if they don't exist send them an invitation to sign up, and place them in that `group`

Currently there is a `user` `group` and `notes` model. I am having difficulties adding a `group_id` to the `notes` so that `notes` belong to the group, and the index for the `group` only shows `notes` what that `group_id`.

**db/migrate**

```
class AddUserIdToNotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :notes, :group_id, :integer
  end
end
```

**models/note.rb**

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end
```

**models/group.rb**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
end
```

**controllers/notes_controller.rb**

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_note, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @notes = Note.where(group_id: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def new
        @note = current_user.notes.build
    end

    def create
        @note = current_user.notes.build(note_params)

        if @note.save
            redirect_to @note
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @note.update(note_params)
            redirect_to @note
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @note.destroy
            redirect_to notes_path
    end

    private

    def find_note
        @note = Note.find(params[:id])
    end

    def note_params
        params.require(:note).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

Comment: Please post the error message/stack trace you are receiving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code in the notes_controller.rb with:

`def index
  @notes = current_user.notes.order("created_at DESC")
end`

You're doing it wrong when you pass the current_user to the group_id