# Rails group_id to Insert statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to add a group(int) to my workorder_controller. I want to store all the workorder data in the same table but filter results based on group not user_id using devise. The idea is, users can see all the user entries for only their group. If there is better way of doing this please let me know.

I have thought about using: 
[Why am I getting NoMethodError for this devise_group call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698367/why-am-i-getting-nomethoderror-for-this-devise-group-call)

It looked like it wasn't working correctly

I also tried to follow this will no luck either:
[Adding group_id to notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904610/adding-group-id-to-notes)

**workorder_controller.rb**

```
class WorkordersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :set_workorder, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /workorders
  # GET /workorders.json
  def index
    @workorders = Workorder.where(group: current_user.group)
  end

  # GET /workorders/1
  # GET /workorders/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /workorders/new
  def new
    @workorder = current_user.workorders.build
  end

  # GET /workorders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /workorders
  # POST /workorders.json
  def create
    @workorder = current_user.workorders.build(workorder_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @workorder.save
        format.html { redirect_to @workorder, notice: 'Workorder was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @workorder }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @workorder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /workorders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /workorders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @workorder.update(workorder_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @workorder, notice: 'Workorder was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @workorder }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @workorder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /workorders/1
  # DELETE /workorders/1.json
  def destroy
    @workorder.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to workorders_url, notice: 'Workorder was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_workorder
      @workorder = Workorder.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def workorder_params
      params.require(:workorder).permit(:contractor_id, :description, :estimatedtime, :startdate, :completiondate, :budgetoverhead, :group)
    end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up)  { |u| u.permit(  :email,:password,:group ,:password_confirmation, roles: []) }
  end
end
```

**ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
    #
    user ||= User.new
  if user.has_role? :admin
    can :manage, :all
  elsif user.has_role? :client
    #workorders
    can :create, Workorder 
    can :update, Workorder 
    can :destroy, Workorder 



    can :read, :all #can read all items bound only to the user login not all users
  else user.has_role? :contractor
    #workorders
    can :create, Workorder 
    can :update, Workorder 
    can :destroy, Workorder 


    can :read, :all #can read all items bound only to the user login not all users
end
    #
    # The first argument to `can` is the action you are giving the user
    # permission to do.
    # If you pass :manage it will apply to every action. Other common actions
    # here are :read, :create, :update and :destroy.
    #
    # The second argument is the resource the user can perform the action on.
    # If you pass :all it will apply to every resource. Otherwise pass a Ruby
    # class of the resource.
    #
    # The third argument is an optional hash of conditions to further filter the
    # objects.
    # For example, here the user can only update published articles.
    #
    #   can :update, Article, :published => true
    #
    # See the wiki for details:
    # https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities
  end
end
```

Output from console:

```
Started POST "/workorders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-19 18:21:18 -0500
Processing by WorkordersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XXXXXtoken hereXXXXX", "workorder"=>{"contractor_id"=>"1", "description"=>"qadsddas", "estimatedtime"=>"111", "startdate(1i)"=>"2017", "startdate(2i)"=>"10", "startdate(3i)"=>"19", "completiondate(1i)"=>"2017", "completiondate(2i)"=>"10", "completiondate(3i)"=>"19", "budgetoverhead"=>"1111"}, "commit"=>"Create Workorder"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (3.4ms)  BEGIN
  Contractor Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `contractors`.* FROM `contractors` WHERE `contractors`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering workorders/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Contractor Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `contractors`.* FROM `contractors` WHERE `contractors`.`group` = 1
  Rendered workorders/_form.html.haml (27.3ms)
  Rendered workorders/new.html.erb within layouts/application (32.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 136ms (Views: 99.4ms | ActiveRecord: 5.9ms)
```

Comment: You should not need to use `devise_group` or "adding group id to notes."  The code you posted here is on the right track.  What specifically, is not working?  Are you getting an error?  Are you trying to ensure that users can only access (i.e. create, read, update, delete) work orders that belong to their group?

Comment: Also, I can tell from `load_and_authorize_resource` that you are using CanCanCan.  It would be helpful if you post your `ability.rb` model.

Comment: What is returned is not "filtered" by group. once I have that figured out I am still lost on how to include it in the parameters during a create. the user_id seems to have no problem attaching itself to the create method. trying to figure out why group will not. Its simple I'm sure but I cannot wrap my brain around it.

Comment: Got it.   I'll  post an answer.

Comment: added ability.rb I'm pretty sure i have correctly implemented it. I was ignoring it until i figured this issue out

Comment: CanCanCan's `load_and_authorize_resource` already loads the record as `@workorder`.  Your `before_action :set_workorder` is causing an extra query per request. Check your logs if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict access to workorders that match the current user's  `group`, I would make the following modifications:

```
# Ensure the group of the work order always matches the current_user's group
def workorder_params
  params.require(:workorder).permit(
    :contractor_id, :description, :estimatedtime, 
    :startdate,:completiondate, :budgetoverhead
  ).merge(group: current_user.group)
end
```

The above will ensure that the `current_user`'s `group` is assigned
to the relevant workorder.

To ensure the selected workorder matches the `group` modify the following:

```
def set_workorder
  @workorder = Workorder.where(id: params[:id], group: current_user.group).first
end
```

You can also restrict access to the `current_user`'s `group` by adding the restriction to `ability.rb`.  For example:

```
can :update, Workorder, group: user.group
```

**Edit:** Removed modification to `create` method.

Comment: it filters the data by group but the parameter still doesn't come across to new

Comment: Hmm. I'd recommend adding `byebug` into your create method and inspecting the results of `workorder_params`.  Does it include group?  You can also use the byebug console to execute `@workorder = Workorder.new(workorder_params)` to see if there are any errors.  You may also try temporarily removing `load_and_authorize_resource` to see if CanCanCan is causing a problem.

Comment: I edited the answer...after some testing, I do not think you need to modify your `create` method.  Merging `group` into `workorder_params` should be the key.

Comment: Bingo! Changed my create method back and it works! Much thanks. I just have the CanCanCan to figure out but I can do that.

Comment: Regarding CanCanCan, you might consider replacing `load_and_authorize_resource` with `authorize_resource` since you are loading manually.  Or you could remove the code that loads/builds your `@workorder` since `load_and_authorize_resource` should take care of that for you.  You'll probably need to experiment.